# Testing similarity scores?

Tags: similarity, distance

I need to calculate similarity between different houses using a series of attributes/properties, and to do that I need to define a certain similarity or distance function. Is there a way to test the similarity scores that the function yields, similarly to how you would test regression results using the MSE?

Comment: Formal hypothesis tests do not make sense (they are about population characteristics, not about individual objects), but you are free to define a distance theshold. If the distance between two objects is below that value, you would call them "similar".

Comment: Please include a sample of data to explain which attributes or properties are present for a more a specific answer. The idea given above Michael M is correct. Represent each house with attribute/properties as a point a vector space. Then you can use standard cosine similarity and other measures.